# SQL - String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've just created a table and now I'm inserting data into that table. However, when I execute my Insert statement the error `String or binary data would be truncated.` occurs.

I've checked the data that would go into my `varchar(100)` columns and **none** of the data are longer than 20. I'm using 100 because I was debugging the issue myself but it's still not clearing up.

```
insert into dbo.tbl_Rooms
(room_id, building, Room_Layout, Capacity)
values  ('B002', 'Beech', null, null),
        ('E002', 'Elm', 'Classroom', null),
        ('E004', 'Elm', 'Classroom', null),
        ('E006', 'Elm', 'Classroom', null),
        ('E028', 'Elm', 'Physics Lab', null),
        ('E102', 'Elm', 'LRC', 72),
        ('E104', 'Elm', 'HE Room', null)
```

The columns using `varchar(100)` are `building` and `room_layout`. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: Can you please post your create table script, just to be sure?

Comment: @shree.pat18 I've found out the problem, I'm going to answer my own question

Comment: Good for you! Would be good if you could include some of the things you tried to check whilst investigating to make your answer a good resource for this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I've found out the issue. Those columns were not the issue. It was the `Room_ID` column which I set, like an imbecile, to `char(3)` rather than `char(4)`. Complete rookie mistake and I feel quite stupid at this very moment in time.

Guys, check your data types, or suffer the consequences as I have!